# How to switch tab programmatically in an xcode 4.3 tab application

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I have a tabcontroller app and I want to forbid the to user go to a certain tab if he is not logged in. Right now I have overridden this tabBarController function.

```
#pragma mark - TabBar Controller functions
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {}
```

I really don't know how to tell the tabBarController to redirect the user to another tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9664368/1126111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example not display the specific view controller while the user is not logged in. After he logged in change the available controllers using

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:yourControllers animated:YES];
```

Or if you really just want to switch programmatically the displayed tab use

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = controllerIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the selected view controller with the property selectedViewController or selectedIndex.

In order to prompt a user to login, it might be better to use a modal view, however.

Comment: Yes, I have a modal panel too, is just if the user dimiss the panel ill end up in the wrong tab the  tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; did the trick.